# Use Paypal Here Credit Card scanner to play a sound in Processing 3

Tags: paypal, processing, webhooks, credit-card, ifttt

I'm trying to make an art project. The basic concept right now is where I use the free PayPal Here card scanner to charge a credit card $0.01 and then by either webhooks or some sort of email receipt solution, have processing take the name of the person who just paid, use that name as a random seed, and play a note that is specific to that person.

My main issue right now is finding out how to connect paying PayPal to some sort of either HTTP POST or just something that Processing 3 can then see what happened.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Use IFTTT to trigger a webhook POST when it receives an email. I set up PayPal to send a receipt to the trigger email, but I have no way to connect IFTTT to Processing.
- I also tried finding out if there was a way to get Bluetooth data from the reader with Wireshark but I couldn't figure out how to scan for Bluetooth. If there is a way to actually crack the reader, (I will put all the reader model numbers at the bottom) with some sort of firmware push with USB, but I couldn't find anything, and I have limited experience with all of that.

I'm not tied to Processing, nor do I need to actually charge anything to get the point across (art, am I right?). Does anyone have any ideas for how I should attempt to pull this off?

PayPal reader numbers:
on the left side of the QR Code, there are three strings, from top to bottom: T3N606-091068, 19182RP10943116, FCC ID: 2ABY6-M0B(or 8)30AA.
on the left side of the QR code, again top to bottom: MO8(or B)30AA, M08(or B)Y-3000